# Realizar acción en onchange de select2 si han elegido un valor especifico

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, select2

tengo un select2 que tiene varios valores, entre ellos uno en especifico que requiere que al seleccionarse automaticamente me muestre un div oculto, o si no esta seleccionado se oculte nuevamente.

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('usos') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">*Tipo de Uso Solicitado:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <select class="select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Seleccionar Tipo de Uso" name="t_usos[]" id="t_usos" style="width: 100%;">
                    @foreach($usos as $uso)
                    <option value="{{$uso->id}}">{{$uso->nombre}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('usos') ? 'has-error' : '' }}" id="agrodiv" style="display:none;">
            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">*Agropecuario:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <select class="form-control" id="agricola" name="agricola">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="true"></option>
                    @foreach($agro as $agrop)
                        <option value="{{$agrop->id}}">{{$agrop->nombre}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

este es mi script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.select2').select2();
$('#t_usos').on("change", function(e) { 
    if ($(this).val() == 1){
        //alert($(this).val());
        $('#agrodiv').show();
    }
    else($(this).val()<>1){
        $('#agrodiv').show();
    }

});});
```

la idea es que si selecciono el valor "Agropecuario" de mi select2, me muestre el DIV oculto, y si en mi select2 no se selecciona el valor "Agropecuario" el div vuelva a ocultarse.

Comment: Tienes algun error?

Comment: Error no, la idea es que si en mi select2 tengo seleccionado "Agopecuario", me muestre un div oculto, de lo contrario que no lo muestre. Por ahora solo me hace lo primero, me muestra el div.  Y solo lo muestra si en mi select2 tengo unicamente "Agropecuario" seleccionado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.select2').select2();
$('#t_usos').on("change", function(e) { 
    var valores = $(this).val();
    if ($.inArray("1", valores) != -1){
        //alert($(this).val());
        $('#agrodiv').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#agrodiv').hide();
    }

});});
```

Solo reemplacé el 1 de la condición, por un "1" como string, y funciona de maravilla. Gracias

Comment: Esta bien a como dices, solo que si en $(this).val() cambia de 1, el div se oculta nuevamente, es decir: si en mi select2 tengo seleccionado unicamente "agricola" funciona perfecto y muestra el div oculto, pero si selecciono otro valor mas ademas del "agricola", el div se oculta. lo unico que quiero que mientras en el Select2 esté seleccionado "agricola", sin imporar si hay mas valores o no, el div oculto aparezca y si quito de la selección el "agricola", el div desaparezca nuevamente.

Comment: ya edite mi respuesta

Comment: no ha funcionado amigo, :( al usar el select, elegi otro valor que no era "agricola", y luego elegi agricola, y no funciono.. :'(

Comment: Muchas gracias @alanfcm